# How can I invoke an exe from Printer Driver?

Tags: driver, wdk

I have created a V4 Printer Driver. I want to invoke another application(.exe)from print driver with print stream as parameter to the application.

Comment: Your question is blurry. Where do you want to call an executable? In which stage of your printer development process? What do you want to do? Providing some more information may be helpful to compose a proper and detailed answer. As a case in point, in v4 printer driver model, GUI of your driver is an executable which can receive any desired parameters.